# Question about Chebyshev inequality

Tags: probability

Let the random variable varialbe $X=X(n)$ have $E(X)=\mu$, $\mu \in \mathbb R.$

And $E(X^2)<\infty$ such that $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\sigma^2/n$ where $\sigma^2>0$ is a fixed positive number and $n\geq1$ is some integer number.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $ a \in(0,1)$ be fixed number. Find the smallest positive integer number $N=N(\epsilon,a)$ such that $\forall \ge N$

$$P(|X-\mu| \ge \epsilon) \le a$$

I know how to get Chebyshev inequality
$P(|X-\mu|>t) \le\operatorname{Var}(X)/t^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{nt^2}$

But now I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already shown that $P(|X-\mu| \ge \epsilon) \le \frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2}$. The right-hand side is a decreasing function of $n$ that converges to zero as $n \to \infty$, so for values of $n$ that are large, this quantity $\frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2}$ is smaller than $a$. Solving for $N$ in $\frac{\sigma^2}{N\epsilon^2}=a$ will give you the answer.